# What’s a good synonym for "system", as in a set of things that can be combined?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am searching for a word which embodies the total of parts (things) which were designed to fit together.  For example:

> A screwdriver “kit” commonly contains a screwdriver handle and screwdriver bits, potentially drive guides, etc.

While the individual pieces might be called *components* or *parts*, how can we refer to the whole?

In the example I gave above, *kit* is already pretty good, but it is a little bit too physical and with too little emphasis on the ability to be compatible with each other.

Some ideas I’ve had so far:

- System — Too generic, fallback if nothing more specific comes along.
- Set — Too generic, contains a nuance less "intent" of being put together, but less ambiguous connotations when compared to system.
- School (as in *school of thought*) — A little bit too lofty or ephemeral. Too close to animals (*school of fish*)?
- Nomenclature — Would be ideal if there were such a thing as an **objeclature* for objects rather than nouns. Brings together the notion of being intentionally designed or selected with the notion that it is more than two items.
- Accessories — Would be great if there were a primary item that stood out among the others. Yet, as with the screwdriver example, I want to include the screwdriver itself in the set.
- Component set — Wordy but otherwise pretty fitting.
- Assemblage — Sounds like the parts were already combined together rather than being bundled together for being assembled by the user.
- Series — Could be fitting, but has a strong temporal scent. Seems to indicate more than one in a line of things, not intended to complement/combine but to replace. *Do you like our new Screwdriver Series X500?*
- Array — Seems to implicate an individual number of items being positioned (that is, located) next to each other rather than the possibility of combining things.
- Collection — Good emphasis on being designed from a single hand (e.g., *our collection of excellent wines*), yet unclear on whether the individual pieces would blend or work together.

I could go on, but I hope you might have better ideas already.

If possible, the word should carry some connotations of:

1. The individual items being designed together.
2. The items go mechanically together.
3. The items belong to the same manufacturing process and level of
   quality.
4. The items being self-contained and needing no outside additions or
   extras.
5. The items being still separate and not assembled into a whole
6. The whole being of value (*kit*, for instance, sounds a little cheap).

Comment: The choice of a word depends on what these things are you are trying to put into one word. What are they? Widgets? Wines?

Comment: Surgical instruments, i.e. physical tools.

Comment: You should have said that from the beginning. Definitely a set. But I think you mean go together, not fit together, that's for puzzles.

Comment: Here is a use of “set”: http://www.dremed.com/catalog/index.php/cPath/205_619?creative=75980496250&keyword=surgical%2520sets&cam=orsupplycom-dre-website&adg=surgical-instrument-sets&gclid=CODj3c_4h88CFcSWvQodGIwN4Q however it might depend on the usage model.  If this is intended to stock an operating room ***set*** would work, If this is intended to be taken into the field then ***kit*** might be more appropriate.

Comment: As far as screwdrivers go, a grandiose name might be “***A complete threaded fastening system***”

Comment: @Jim: The link you gave for set illustrates perfectly why I am looking for something apart from set: These "sets" are lumped together because you need all of them to treat a particular surgical case. They are not made to be combined with each other. So I am looking for a good synonym.

Comment: could you please elaborate on the context in which you’ll use this term.  It is often the case that things are purchased with “*some assembly required*” but we still talk about it as if it were put together (I bought a new bookcase yesterday) unless we are specifically talking about it in the context of its assembly (it’s still in pieces because I haven’t put it together yet).  But when i’m in the store the sales guy will say here’s your bookcase, not here’s your box of bookcase components, or here’s your bookcase kit.

Comment: For surgical tools, a bit of google searching suggests you could use 'surgical kit', or less commonly 'surgical instrument set'. But that's not really the question that was asked.

Answer (score 4):

How about **set**?

From Merriam-Webster:

> **set**: a number of things of the same kind that belong or are used together

**Set** carries the following connotations specified by the OP:

- The individual items having been designed together
- The items fitting mechanically together
- The items belong to the same manufacturing
  process and level of quality
- The items being self-contained and
  needing no outside addition or extras
- The items being still separate and not assembled into a whole
- The whole being of value ("kit" for instance - sounds a little cheap)

Comment: Yes, I should have thought of that. The mathematical terms in English and French respectively are *set* and *ensemble*.

Comment: The same arrangement with socket spanners is usually called 'a socket set'

Comment: I always feel that "set" is very generic and while it can convey the meaning, it could also mean that all the parts are just lumped together (tire set). In the mathematical sense "A collection of individual things".

Comment: A set of tools. OK for any type of tools, surgical or otherwise.

Comment: @ChristopherOezbek I don't think of the parts as just lumped together, i.e., as in a random collection. They are intended to be used together and to be sufficient to enable the user to perform a variety of closely related tasks. An obvious example is **tool set**.

Comment: @ChristopherOezbek who is lumping anything together> A set of something is never "lumped" together. I think we are reaching overkill on this question, myself.

Answer (score 0):

How about *ensemble* ? While this often refers to a collection of clothing (in the sense of *wardrobe*, although that can also refer to the piece of furniture) in English, it also is used in statistical mechanics in the sense you describe. In French, it's meaning is much closer to what you want. And the pronunciations are almost the same.

Comment: Dear David! Thanks that is an excellent suggestion. It conveys well, that these things are meant to be together and combine well. The only sad part is that it might not be English "enough" and easily misunderstood.

Comment: This answer has received two negative votes. I have no idea why.

Comment: I don't know either.

Answer (score 0):

***Knock-down kit / knockdown kit / knocked-down kit*** , or simply ***knockdown***

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knock-down_kit):

> A **knock-down kit** is a kit containing the parts needed to assemble a
>   product. The parts are typically manufactured in one country or
>   region, then exported to another country or region for final assembly.
>   Variant names include knockdown kit, knocked-down kit, or simply
>   knockdown, and the abbreviated KD or CKD.
>
> A common form of knock-down is a complete knock-down (CKD), which is a
>   complete kit needed to assemble a product.

Comment: This sounds like a British use. *Kit* used in this sense is not that often seen in Canada or the US.

Comment: @DavidHandelman it's an industry specific term, more or less an automotive and heavy industry tax scheme as such it's used industry wide and worldwide.

Comment: For me the connotations are too strong on being disassembled into pieces  from a whole for reassembly later on and that all pieces must be reassembled to make one product. No notion of partial configurations being valid.

Answer (score 0):

*Assembly*

Merriam-Webster:

6

a :  the fitting together of manufactured parts into a complete machine, structure, or unit of a machine

b :  a collection of parts so assembled

Say your car was damaged in a minor accident.  The mechanic tells you it's not possible to buy the individual part to replace the headlight lens, or cover; you have to order the whole **assembly** (which includes the headlight and the indicator light and the cover).

You can also say

*module*

Think of the lunar module!

---

Trying again.

*Outfit*

When you buy a trombone *outfit*, you get the trombone, the case (perhaps with backpack straps), and the care kit, which includes Pocket-Sized Spray Water Bottle, Slide Oil, Slide Cream, Flexible Cleaning Snake, Mouthpiece Brush and Polishing Cloth.

Comment: Too much in violation of point 5: "The items being still separate and not assembled into a whole."

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice that requirement.  I will try again.

Answer (score -1):

What about **apparatus** ?

It is a collection or combination of instruments, machinery, tools, parts or other equipment having a particular function or intended for a specific purpose.

Example:

> *Power transmission apparatus: all components of the mechanical system
>   which transmit energy to the part of the machine performing the work.
>   These components include flywheels, pulleys, belts, connecting rods,
>   couplings, cams, spindles, chains, cranks, and gears*.

Comment: Worthy, strongly mechanical, but also very much already assembled. I would like to put more emphasis on the pieces than the whole.